# How can I get the Methodlist while iterating?

Tags: matlab

I want to iterate through all classes and packages in a special path.
After that, I want to get the MethodList.

In the command window I can use following and it’s working fine:

```
a = ?ClassName;
a.MethodList(X);
```

Now I separate this into a function:

```
function s =  befehlsreferenz(path)
s = what(path); % list MATLAB files in folder

for idx = 1:numel(s.classes)
    c = s.classes(idx);
    b = ?c;
    b.MethodList(0);        
end
end
```

**I get an error:**
Too many outputs requested.  Most likely cause is missing [] around left hand side that has a comma separated list
expansion. Error in  (line 7) b.MethodList(0);

While debugging I can see:

c: 1x1 cell = ‘Chapter’ 
b: empty 0x0 meta.class

Why is b empty? How can I get the methodlist?

---

## 1 Edit:

Here is an example class, also not working with it.

```
classdef TestClass
    %TESTCLASS Summary of this class goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here
    
    properties
    end
    
    methods
        function [c] = hallo(a)
            c = 1;
        end
    end
    
end
```

Comment: please post the code of class `Chapter`.

Comment: It is not my code, so I don't want to publish it. :( But I tried it with a few classes and it's not working. Do you think I need to add something in the classes?

Comment: please post at least one demo class which exposes this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When struggling with operators in Matlab, it's typically the best choice to use the underlying function instead, which is `meta.class.fromname(c)`

Relevant documentation: http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/metaclass.html

Further it seems `s.classes(idx);` is a cell, use cell indexing: `s.classes{idx} ;`